# Is it possible to comment out the css attribute in another file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm solving a problem with style settings. Namely, in the desktop view, the width of the toggle is defined by the text,

[image]

while in the mobile view, it has the same width as the header.

[image]

I came up with a simple solution in the browser in debug mode. Just "uncheck" width.

[image]

[image]

The problem is how to write this using CSS / JS. This way, the "comment out" code so setting an empty value

`$(".tg-site-layout--default #primary").css("width", "");`

will not have the same effect.

But, is it even possible to "comment out" a code in another file? Or can it be solved in another way?

Please help

Thank you

PS. It's on [this page](http://testtheme.euweb.cz/index.php/elementor-1177/) - It is a website in wordpress for testing purposes only.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset_style_sheet

Comment: A reset stylesheet isn't related to removing style rules. It is possible to alter style rules using JS, but it's complicated and not a good practice. It's better to just override the value with the value you want.